# Java - Identifying a comment in a string line using regex

Tags: java, regex

How would I identify a "comment" in a string? My "comments" start with `*`.

For example `*this is a comment.` would be recognized as a comment. 
 
This my my code:

```
public static boolean isComment(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    String comment = "'*'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"; //Somehow using *[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ does not work.

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(comment);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    if(m.find())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you give us a couple of examples of such comments?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Also, your whole method can be replaced with `return Pattern.compile("'*'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+").matcher(s.replaceAll("\\s+","")).find();`.

Comment: It's probably because you aren't escaping the `*`, since it's also an operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for your method:

```
String s="hey *this is a comment*";
String comment = "\\*[^*]*\\*"; 

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(comment);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if(m.find())
    System.out.println("found you, bad comment!");
else
    System.out.println("it looks like there is no comment...");
```

**input:**

```
hey *this is a comment*
```

**output:**

```
found you, bad comment!
```

**input:**

```
I am not a comment right?
```

**output:**

```
it looks like there is no comment...
```

You can adapt it depending on your exact needs:

If comments should start at the beginning of the lines use:

```
"^\\*[^*]*\\*"
```

If you do not need a closing `*` for the message to be identified as a comment, then use:

```
"\\*.*"
```

**Homework:**

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score -2):

Use this regex `"^\\*"` string instead `"'*'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"`.

I hope help you

Comment: Why is unclear? If he need to know if an string start with '*' the rigth regex for use is "^\\*" and not "'*'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+". He just need to change your regex for mine.